# How might I apply multiple security mechanisms to a Swagger-generated REST service?

Tags: rest, unit-testing, security

I have generated JAX-RS stubs for a REST service using Swagger and want to set up the security.

The security side is very new to me and I would like to use standards as far as possible. (In the past, for other J2EE applications, I have used `Filter`s to handle Authentication which put User objects into a `Session`. As I understand it, `Sessions` should be avoided for REST.)

There are 4 types of user who will access the services

- Customers and business partners (Authentication via oAuth or similar)
- Employees (Authentication via NTLM & LDAP)
- Developers (Mock authentication/authorisation of some kind)
- Integration test (JUnit with pre-defined users and roles)

Is it possible to define a security mechanism which would handle all of these users?

How would I use the Swagger security directives?

Am I making this more complicated than it needs to be?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [open source API gateway](https://tyk.io/) like Tyk? Here’s a link to some handy info on [API Security](https://tyk.io/docs/security/) in the tyk docs.

And here is a blog post that describes taking [a layered approach to API Security](https://tyk.io/blog/how-secure-is-your-api/) that goes beyond the gateway.

Disclosure: I work for Tyk!